# COM DLL method using referenced enumeration

Tags: vb.net, dll, vb6

I've created a VB.NET application in VS2015 using x86 compiler and .net target framework 4.5.2

I created a RCW for a COM dll written in VB6 using tlbimp, called "NETLib.dll" and added this interop as a reference to my project.

This COM dll holds the following method:

```
Function DoSomething(sData As String, iData As Integer, eData As RefLib.enumDat) As Integer
```

within the class `claSomeClass`.

My issue: As soon as I use this method in my VB.NET project like the following

```
Public Class MyClass
    Private oNetLibClass As NetLib.claSomeClass

    Sub New()

        oNetLibClass = New NetLib.claSomeClass
        Dim eVal = RefLib.enumDat.Foo

        Dim lReturn = oNetLibClass.DoSomething("DoIt", 1, eVal)

    End Sub
End Class
```

I get an error:

> BC30652: Reference required to assembly 'RefLib, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' containing the type 'enumDat'.
>   Add one to your project.

for the line `Dim lReturn = oNetLibClass.DoSomething("DoIt", 1, eVal)` even though I added RefLib (which also is a COM dll) as an interop to my VB.NET project.

Why do I get this error?

P.S: The line `Dim eVal = RefLib.enumDat.Foo` is not throwing any error, so I assumed the reference was added correctly...

Comment: Do the version numbers match? Is the version of the RefLib reference you added 2.0.0.0?

Comment: Yes, it is 2.0.0.0 and also culture=0

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: This smells like a Roslyn issue.  The code certainly doesn't get put the test very often and gives the compiler a splitting headache, it has to convert a Boolean to an enum type.  Having to hunt for a possible conversion operator might trigger the bug.  Do consider writing sane code, surely Dim eVal = RefLib.enumDat.Foo was intended.  Check the two assembly references, their "Embed Interop Types" setting should agree.  If that doesn't help then click the [New Issue button](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues).